# Aumentar o tamanho do combobox plugin Select2

Tags: css, jquery-select2

Preciso que o combobox plugin Select2 (https://plugins.jquery.com/select2/) que está acima fique com o mesmo efeito do combo que está abaixo conforme a imagem, ou seja, aumentar o tamanho da largura sem cobrir os campos al lado, é possível ?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que você já tentou fazer? Qual código está mexendo? Qual `css`? Poste o código referente ao seu problema bem como informações acerca do que já tentou para resolver o problema, só assim poderemos guiá-lo melhor para a resolução do problema.

Comment: Celso de uma olhada no link que consta na pergunta, lá tem todas as informações inclusive o css e eu não consigo identificar exatamente o que tem que alterar no CSS.

Comment: Não adianta apenas olhar o css bruto do plugin. Até por que eu teria que ficar 'caçando' a informação. Ele está inserido dentro de um contexto (o seu site/app) que pode interferir diretamente no comportamento do plugin, independente do css original dele. Sempre forneça as informações, códigos sobre seu problema. Nunca através de links externos.

Comment: Estou perguntando pois imagino que alguém tenha passado por isso, e tenha uma idéia de como resolve-lo, necessariamente não precisa ser você pode ser qualquer outra pessoa que tenha passado por essa situação.

Comment: Não é uma questão de já ter passado por isso. É uma questão de fornecer as informações mínimas para que qualquer pessoa, tenha ela passado por isso ou não, possa lhe ajudar. Esse é o propósito da comunidade. Mas, se não é o seu caso, desculpe, mas não da pra ficar caçando informações e adivinhar qual o cenário do seu código.